# Why is a function with an explicit "this parameter" assignable to a less-specific signature?

Tags: typescript

If function `a`'s signature requires that it be invoked with an explicit `this` type (i.e., `this: { x: number }`), why is it assignable to a less-specific signature (i.e., `() => string`)?

Run-time error resulting because of this:
[image: Runtime Error]

TypeScript-Handbook: [this parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters).

Would this be something covered by a new `--strict` option or is it a limitation of the previously-existing ~`--strictFunctionTypes` option?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that if left unspecified, the type of `this` for a function is implicitly `any`, so your full definition would be:

```
function a(this: {x : number}) {
    return "";
}

function b(fn: (this: any)=> string) { }
```

These two function are compatible since `any` can be assigned to any other type including `{x : number}`, and this behavior is allowed even under `strictFunctions` and `strict`.

The only way to ensure incompatibility is to define `this` on `b` as being `void` as an expression of the fact that no `this` will be passed to `fn`:

```
function a(this: {x : number}) {
    return "";
}
function b(fn: (this: void)=> string) { }

b(a); //error
```

As to the matter of why this is not the default behavior, the compiler team has an open issue on this, so my guess is they are looking into it. See the [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7968) and a [discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7689) on the topic

Comment: This is sort of right but I feel like the question is asking why the type system doesn't track the need for `this`, even though by inspection it's clearly required, and doesn't report an error for the call to `b` with `a`. `a()`  could technically always be an error.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I think this a matter of an unimplemented feature, since `this` is implicitly `any` and `this` is treated as any other parameter for compatibility.. compatibility is the conclusion the compiler reaches

Comment: @AluanHaddad, Addde relevant issue and discussion, apparently they are looking into this :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thanks for linking to that issue. I feel a little bad I didn't search for (or suggest) `--strictThis` myself yesterday.

Comment: @SlurpTheo `strictThis` is exactly the thing I searched for on GitHub, seemed like the obvious name to call it :)